# Integer product problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all integers n for which the number $$(n+3)(n-1)$$ is also an integer
I tried. According to me for any replacement of n by integer $$(n+3)(n-1)$$ produces integer. What is the right argument?

Comment: The integers are a ring which is closed under addition and multiplication so $(n+3)(n-1)$ is an integer for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Perhaps $\,(n+3)(n-1)\,$ is a typo for $\,(n+3)/(n-1).\,$ Maybe you can infer that from the context. What is the source?

Comment: Given your [next exercise](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/863484/242) is of said quotient form, probably that was also meant here.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is so basic, I'll answer with a bit more pedantic approach.

The integers are axiomatized after the naturals, $\Bbb N$, which is a nonempty set containing an element $1$ and satisfying the existence of a successor function $\sigma(n)=n+1$ and to be well-ordered by $\sigma$. The addition is defined by talking about applications of the successor function, and subtraction is introduced formally when $m>n$ then $m-n=k$ where $n+k=m$ and then the negative integers are appended "virtually" first by adding $0$ into the mix formally and also the others to formally satisfy the order reversing relation

$$m<n\iff ``-m">``-n"$$

Then by definition and induction, if we are given an integer $n$ we can add a natural number $N$ large enough so that $n+N>2$. Hence by definition

$$N+(n-1)>1\text{ and }N+n+3>1$$

are natural numbers, hence $n-1$ and $(n+3)$, which are virtual differences of naturals are also integers.

After adding in the definition of multiplication on the naturals by recursion on addition (these are integers, so induction can achieve this) we achieve that the product of two integers is also an integer.