# Integral values and reducibility of fractions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all integers $n$ such that $$\frac {3n+4}{n+2}$$ is also an integer. I started substituting integral values except $n=-2$ but I could not reduce

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. $$ \frac{3n+4}{n+2} = \frac{3(n+2) - 2}{n+2} = 3 - \frac 2{n+2}. $$

Comment: Remark that this is equivalent to applying the Polynomial Remainder Theorem. But since we need only the remainder, not the quotient, it is generally simpler to use modular arithmetic rather than the full-blown polynomial division algorithm, e.g. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ n\!+\!2\!:\ \color{#0a0}{n\equiv -2}\,\Rightarrow\, \underbrace{3n\!+\!4\equiv 3(\color{#0a0}{-2})+4\equiv -\color{#c00}2}\,$

Therefore, $ $we deduce that $\,n\!+\!2\mid 3n\!+\!4\iff n\!+\!2\mid\, \color{#c00}2$

**Remark** $\ $ More generally $\,n-a\mid f(n)\iff n-a\mid f(a),\,$ for any polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ with integer coefficients. The proof is the same as above (or one can use the Polynomial Remainder Theorem).